# Reduce the pipeline script for running multiple jobs parallel

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have below snippet for getting the matching job name then trigger all of them run parallelly.

Shared library file `CommonPipelineMethods.groovy`

```
import jenkins.instance.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.Result
import hudson.model.*

import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.*

class PipelineMethods {

def buildSingleJob(downstreamJob) {
    return {
        result = build job: downstreamJob.fullName, propagate: false
        echo "${downstreamJob.fullName} finished: ${result.rawBuild.result}"
        }
    }

}
return new PipelineMethods();
```

The main Jenkinsfile script:

```
def commonPipelineMethods;

pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Load Common Methods into Pipeline') {
            def JenkinsFilePath = '/config/jenkins/jobs'
            commonPipelineMethods = load "${WORKSPACE}${JenkinsFilePath}/CommonPipelineMethods.groovy"
        }
        stage('Integration Test Run') {
            steps {
                script {
                    matchingJobs = commonPipelineMethods.getIntegrationTestJobs(venture_to_test, testAgainst)
                    parallel matchingJobs.collectEntries{downstreamJob-> [downstreamJob.name, commonPipelineMethods.buildSingleJob(downstreamJob)]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script works fine but looking at from `Map .... parallel step for parallel` the script is a bit busy and not easy to get it. The main purpose of this is I want to reduce the pipeline script to be cleaner and easy for others to help maintain. Something simple like calling the external methods as `matchingJobs = commonMethods.getIntegrationTestJobs(venture, environment)`, so others can understand it right away and know what the code does in this context.

I tried several ways to improve it but seem if it put part of them into building the single job outside the pipeline itself but into the external library, for example

```
def buildSingleJobParallel (jobFullName) {
        String tempPipelineResult = 'SUCCESS'
        result = build job: jobFullName, propagate: false
        echo "${jobFullName} finished: ${result.rawBuild.result.toString()}"
            if (result.rawBuild.result.isWorseThan(Result.SUCCESS)) {
                tempPipelineResult = 'FAILURE'
                }
    }
```

then Jenkins prompted me that
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: PipelineMethods.build() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[job:test_1, propagate:false]]`

I can understand that `build()` method is from Jenkins Pipeline Build Steps Plugins, but I failed to import it and use it inside that `commonMethods` library (this local library I just use `load ()` method in the very first phase of my pipeline script.

So my question is

- Could I use Jenkins Pipeline Build Step plugins inside the external library I mentioned above?
- If it's not possible for the first question, I wonder if there's any cleaner way to make my script simpler and cleaner?

Thanks, everybody!

Comment: It should be possible to extract the method in the Jenkinsfile which makes having a look at the method definition easier.

Comment: I also quite like to use collectEntries instead of a raw for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if it runnable and looks clearer but i just tried to put all together from question and comments

```js
//function that returns closure to be used as one of parallel jobs
def buildSingleJobParallel(steps, mjob){ 
    return {
        def result = steps.build job: mjob.fullName, propagate: false
        steps.echo "${mjob.fullName} finished: ${steps.result.rawBuild.result}"
        if (result.rawBuild.result.isWorseThan(Result.SUCCESS)) {
            steps.currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        }
    }
}



stage('Integration Test Run') {
    steps {
        script {
            //build map<jobName, Closure> and run jobs in parallel
            parallel matchingJobs.collectEntries{mjob-> [mjob.name, buildSingleJobParallel(this, mjob)]}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @dagget for making it clearer. In fact,  I want to take `buildSingleJobParallel` out of pipeline script itself and put it in the shared libraries for the common method I wanna use in another file. And the problem is `build job : <jobname>` is not available outside the Pipeline script.

Comment: you still can do that: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps

Comment: I tried to import the relevant libraries into the shared local library, but it still prompted MethodException that `build()` is not found within the Script file.
```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.* 
```

Comment: ok, i added how approximately pipeline steps could be called from external library.

Comment: Thank you @daggett  for answering me. I think should have copied the current pipeline scripts & how I load the external shared library here so that you could understand the context better. Could you please have to take a look at the edited description above? Thanks again.

Comment: See the first parameter to buildSingleJobParallel and how it used.

Comment: I think I can trigger the build from your suggestion, to put addtional `steps` and `this` into mine  !!! However, i think it prompted me ```hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: result for class: WorkflowScript```, which a bit confused for me.

Comment: declare the result variable : `def result = steps.build ...` and then check all points where you accessing `result` property.

Comment: Thanks, @daggett. I'm able to run it properly. My wrong is to declare `result` outside the closure and also set `steps.result.rawBuild.result` instead of `result.rawBuild.result` itself.